# What are good naming conventions for linking tables

Tags: naming-conventions, naming

What is a good naming convention for naming linking tables? I have a school project and we are modifying the orig data for the project.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please read: [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what language you're going for here, but you can try database naming conventions. This link may help you decide. 
http://efsavage.com/blog/posts/database_naming_conventions/

Comment: I wasn't looking for dbase naming but join/link table naming conventions, I found it finally.

Comment: what I found on the net was things like table1LINKtable2 or table1JOINtable2 or table1TOtable2 or table1_table2, etc. The thing is just make it so that it at least makes sense to you (and hopefully others)